# Seekbar not reaching it max value specifically on MI device (works fine for other devices)

Tags: android, android-seekbar

This works with all other devices and android version,issue is specific to Xiaomi MI devices

```
<SeekBar  android:id="@+id/sb_years"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:max="25"
          android:min="1"
          android:progress="5"
       android:progressDrawable="@drawable/drawable_seekbar_yellow_component"
          android:splitTrack="false"
          android:thumb="@drawable/slider_icon"
          tools:targetApi="lollipop" />
```

```
<item
    android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_seekbar_yellow_fill"/>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_seekbar_yellow_progress" />
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code on my MI device and its working fine I just removed these two lines and everything worked fine.

```
android:progressDrawable="@drawable/drawable_seekbar_yellow_component"
android:thumb="@drawable/slider_icon"
```

Comment: I tried removing these lines,not working at my end,tried on MI A1

Comment: can you share the whole xml  and your activity class as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Found solution to this.
This is the issue with seekbar when you specify both min & max
Removed the min condition & handled it programatically

The new code for seekbar is

```
<SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/sb_years"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:max="25"
                android:progress="5"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/drawable_seekbar_yellow_component"
                android:splitTrack="false"
                android:thumb="@drawable/slider_icon"
                tools:targetApi="lollipop" />
```